# Live notification/chat in django

Tags: django, websocket

I am making a website with django now and I want to implement a live notification feature like the one on facebook or SE.

I did some research and it seems although there's two options: ajax long polling and websockets, the latter is the way to go.

However, as you know the go to plugin for websocket 'socket.io' turns out to be a node.js plugin and the django port only seems to support python 2 and the project seems pretty much dead. I am using python 2.7 as my project interpreter but I want to future proof myself so that if I upgrade to python3 later, I don't find myself not being able to use this functionality.

So my question is this: 
Is there a straight forward and future ready way to implement websocket which will be used to send live notifications and chats in django env?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Django itself is build in blocking manner, i.e. with *synchronous* approach. So, you **cannot** open persistent websocket with django app, as it will block entire django thread.

If you want to enable notification/chat within django project environment, i would recommend to use [centrifuge](https://github.com/centrifugal/centrifuge). It is written in python, but async (non-blocking) framework is used: [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/).

But, you don't need to even know how it works, as it provides simple REST api to communicate with it.

Simplified workflow, check [docs](https://centrifuge.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for more details:

1. Start `centrifuge` at same server, as your django project (or on another but with low latency between them)
2. Your front-end will open websocket with centrifuge, not with django project.
3. When you need to send notification, send it to centrifuge from django via REST api, and centrifuge will deliver it to needed clients!

I've already tried it and it works!

Comment: This seems like a viable solution. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @stalk : It sounds very promising thanks for this! Do you know if it's compatible with PaaS hosting platform like heroku?

Comment: @DavidW. haven't tried, but according to [docs](https://centrifuge.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/deploy.html#heroku) it is possible to run centrifuge on heroku

Comment: @stalk: when you say: "Start centrifuge at same server", does that mean that Centrifuge (Tornado) and Django can share a same host/port ??

Comment: @DavidW. No, of course django project and centrifuge (tornado) must be run on different ports

Comment: One note to this answer: Centrifuge can't notify Django project when client writes to Websocket. New user-generated content must be send to Django backend in a standard manner - i.e. via AJAX or normal POST request - then data should be validated in your Django app, maybe saved into database as usual and then you can send message into Centrifuge and this message will be broadcasted to all clients. It's possible to create Websocket app without using Django backend at all - but this is a rare case as usually we need to process new data (check permissions, validate, save)

Comment: @AlexEmelin thanks, updated the answer. Just thought, that if we'll turn on "is_watching" project flag, then we can receive those messages by REST api. But now i see, that it will be shown in centrifuge web interface only.

Comment: Centrifuge project is no more maintained. They've migrated it to Go language and call it Centrifugo now.

Comment: @xyres thanks for pointing this, just wanted to say that Go version (Centrifugo) still can be used in the same way with Django

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't provide what you're looking for out of the box. You'll have to use a third party library. One that works across frameworks is [Pusher](https://pusher.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you must go for [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) it gives you awesome synchronization and any how you are going to use chat on frontend so its does not have to do anything with django environment so you can update you backend asynchron in callback with firbase. Also firebase with AngularJS provides you really really awesome three way binding.